# Using HIPS as support for PLA printing?

Tags: pla, support-material

I have a question. I have a dual extruder printer and I want to try using HIPS for printing. Can I use PLA as my main material and HIPS for supports?

Searching online I found combinations of ABS + HIPS mentioned. No where is it mentioned that It can be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can as PLA is not affected by Limonene (the chemical used to dissolve the HIPS) but it is not recommended as the print temperatures for each material (~180C for PLA and ~230C for HIPS) are quite far apart and the PLA may not stick to the HIPS.

A better choice would be PVA which prints ~185C and dissolves in water but this material has its own set of fun issues.

*Temperatures are estimates, different vendors may have different temperatures.

Comment: PolyVinyl Acetate?

Comment: @NH. PolyVinyl Alcohol